# File not updating after reading

Tags: vb.net

I have a process that runs multiple times and uses a data file to pass info from one to the next.  This data is not always getting updated and passed.

Here is the code.

```
Dim FileContent() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(iFile)
For line As Integer = 0 To UBound(FileContent)
    TempString = FileContent(line)

    If TempString.Contains("BegYear") Then
        BegYear = CInt(TempString.Substring(9,))

    ElseIf TempString.Contains("EndYear") Then
        EndYear = CInt(TempString.Substring(9,))
    End If

Next line

' Update all the run dates for the next run in the text file
BegYear2 = BegYear + TimeLength
EndYear2 = EndYear + TimeLength
FileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(iFile)
FileContent(LBound(FileContent)+2) = "BegYear: " & BegYear2
FileContent(LBound(FileContent)+3) = "EndYear: " & EndYear2
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(iFile,FileContent)
```

What is happening is that the runs are 15 seconds apart but for some reason, the BegYear line is not getting updated but the EndYear line is.  Is there a way to clear any memory or close out the file when this process is done?

BTW, if it runs 20 times, the first 10 (or so) work fine. It is the later runs that have the issue.

Comment: The posted code won't compile.

Comment: It was a code snippet.  The code is for WWB.net as the tool used but it uses vb syntax.

Comment: So it allows this: `TempString.Substring(9, )` ?

Comment: Yes.  TempString is defined as a string.  (Dim TempString as String)  It was further up in the code so I missed adding it to the question.

Comment: I'm referring to the missing information after the comma.

Comment: Yes, from column 9 to the end of the string.

Comment: Right.  vb.net shows that as "Argument not specified for parameter 'length'"  I'm trying to understand if what you are saying is that is legitimate code for this WWB.net thing you are using.

Comment: Yes.  That code will give you the substring from column 9 to the end of TempString.  But that is not the issue.  It is related to that the code appears to be not releasing the file so the next run can read it with the correct data updated.  The System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(iFile,FileContent) does not seem to be working.  Is there another command I would need to save the file and free the memory?

Comment: The only reason I kept harping on that was due to your lack of documenting your question appropriately.  I don't know what WWB is or how it affects the *vb.net code* you present.  Use a boolean variable like `bool isRunning;` and add an if check at the top `if (!isRunning) {...}` and in the first line set it to true and then include the rest of your code block.  At the end of the if block, set it back to false `isRunning = false;`  Per your own comment though, the code works.  Is the file growing?  Maybe the file is taking too long to process after x number of iterations.

Comment: Yes Lars, the code works.  And it does update the file.  
But there are times when we get results that are different.  The total process takes 90+ minutes and this is the INPUT data file that gets read into the script so I can't wait for the process to finish.  What it appears to be doing is that the writing process is only updating the EndYear line and not the BegYear line, in some instances.  Other times it works perfectly.
According to the WWB.net and vb.NET descriptions of the ReadAllLines and WriteAllLines is that they open/close the file immediately.  This does not seem to be working.

Comment: To clarify what WWB.net is.  WinWrap® Basic.
Use '#Language "WWB.NET" for Visual Basic.NET(TM) compatibility and we do this.

Comment: Do you have to read the file twice?  Doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: What exactly is it that you are trying to do? Are the files logfiles? Are the dates sequential? If the loop is big (file contains 10's of thousands of lines) each time you loop through the loop the values of BegYear/EndYear can changes each time they appear in the text, but you dont save them till the end of the loop...